# C++ Linear Progression, code won't work

Tags: c++11, linear-regression

Please help me to understand what is wrong in this first line of my code it keeps saying expected unqualified id before public.

```
public class LinearRegressionModel extends RegressionModel {

  /* The y intercept of the straight line */
  private double a;

  /* The gradient of the line */
  private double b;

  ...
}
```

Error :

```
[Error] expected unqualified-id before 'public'
```

Comment: You shouldn't post images of text, you should post the text. But, since I looked: that's Java, not C++.

Comment: Paste code here, not in image.

Comment: The code in the image is not C++, it looks like Java. And that's probably why you get errors. Java is not C++, and no C++ compiler can compile Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor thing: it's written in the wrong language! C++ would look more like this:

```
class LinearRegressionModel : public RegressionModel {
private:
  double a;
  double b;

  ...

public:
  /* public stuff here */
}
```